# Appending Something before textbox rendered using inputfield/outputfield?

Tags: visualforce

I want to append `$` sign before my textbox which is rendering through inputfield?

How can I do this ?

Here I have attached am image.[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're not going to be able to do this without playing around with the DOM after the page is generated if you're using `<apex:inputField>`.

You could use `<apex:outputLabel>` and `<apex:inputText>` so that you can put it between the two (or put it in the label value attribute), but that's not a particularly nice solution.

Personally I'd just edit the label for the field to include a dollar sign in brackets after the main label "My Field ($)".

Do you have multiple currency support enabled in your organisation? If so it may not be appropriate to simply use a dollar sign every time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to do this in a looks-like-standard-UI Visualforce page. In my solution I've included element ids in my markup for identification purposes.

There's a tag called apex:pageBlockSectionItem (below, look for id="item") whose sole purpose is these little UI tricks where you need to shoe-horn in something non-standard into a pageBlockSection's cell. It is limited to two child tags, the first for the label (id="label"), the second for the data (id="data"). If your second tag is an output panel (compiles to  on the HTML), you can put anything inside of it and it will fit in the data column with the correct style and everything. In my case, it is an outputText and an inputField (id="dollar" and id="inputField").

```
<apex:page id="page" standardController="Position__c">
    <apex:form id="form" >
        <apex:pageBlock id="block" mode="edit" >
            <apex:pageblockSection id="detailSection" >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="item" >
                    <apex:outputLabel id="label" value="{!$ObjectType.Position__c.fields.Max_Pay__c.label}"/>
                    <apex:outputPanel id="data" >
                        <apex:outputText id="dollar" value="$"/>&nbsp;
                        <apex:inputField id="inputField" value="{!Position__c.Max_Pay__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
<apex:page>
```

This markup results in the page below:

[image: Rendered Visualforce Page]

I would also recommend, once you get this working, to use an inspector to understand how VF is building the HTML on render. I've done this below. It helped me make sense of what exactly happens when you add an inputField to a pageBlockSection, and how pageBlockSectionItem then works to mimic that look and feel.

[image: Inspector View of Visualforce HTML Output]

Comment: great!!!!!!!!!!